# How do I create a bootstrap 4 slider with images that are responsive both horizontally and vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to create a bootstrap 4 slider with images that are responsive to changes in both width and height. So far I have this:

```
<section id="carousel-landing" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>
                Title 1.
          </h1>
          <p>
              Sed egestas sapien non mauris euismod
              at aliquet orci euismod
              1.455 €
          </p>
        </div>
        <img src="images/landing/image.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>
                Title 2
          </h1>
          <p>
              Sed egestas sapien non mauris euismod
              at aliquet orci euismod
              1.455 €
          </p>
        </div>
        <img src="images/landing/image.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>
                Title 3
          </h1>
          <p>
              Sed egestas sapien non mauris euismod
              at aliquet orci euismod
              1.455 €
          </p>
        </div>
        <img src="images/landing/image.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-landing" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-landing" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</section>

#carousel-landing {
margin-top: $margin-navbar-height;
min-height: 400px;
max-height: calc(100vh - 180px);
carousel-item {
    max-height: 100%;
}
.carousel-caption {     
    bottom: auto;
    position: static;
    padding-top: 0;
    text-shadow: none;
    top: 0;
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        margin-right: 25%;
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
    @media (max-width: 991px) {
        padding: 0 20px;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;    
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
        margin-right: 20%;
        margin-left: 20%;
    }
}
h1 {
    color: $black;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: $font-bold;
    line-height: 1.07;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    @media (max-width: 543px) {
        font-size: 36px;    
    }
    @media (min-width: 544px) and (max-width: 767px) {
        font-size: 48px;    
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        margin: 0 auto 14px;    
    }
}   
p {
    color: $black;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        margin: 0 80px 21px;
    }
    text-align: center;

}   
img {
    display: block;
    margin: $margin-center;
    max-width: 97%;
    @media (max-width: 991px) {
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
}   
.carousel-control {
    color: $gray-8;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: none;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50px;
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        display: none;  
    }
}   
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
    background: url('../images/icons/nav-prev.svg') right center no-repeat;
    font-size: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 50px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-next {
    background: url('../images/icons/nav-next.svg') left center no-repeat;
}   
.carousel-control .icon-prev:before {
    content: ' ';
}   
.carousel-control .icon-next:before {
    content: ' ';
}   
.carousel-control.right,
.carousel-control.left {
    background-image: none;
}
}
```

I need to make slider images resize both when the browser resizes horizontally and vertically and aspect ratio of images must be preserved. The slider needs to have a minimum height of 400px. 
Note: I set the caption to position static so that it is placed above the images because it was drawn that way in the design.

I tried various combinations with jquery and right now I'm stuck with something like this, but it doesn't preserve the aspect radio of images and it leaves me with unwanted space beneath the image after I resize the height of the browser bellow 400px.

```
$(window).load(imgResize);
$(window).on('resize',imgResize);

function imgResize() {  
    var navHeight = $("nav").outerHeight(),
    textHeight = 265;
    height = $(window).height() - navHeight - textHeight;   
    $("#carousel-landing .carousel-item img").css({ 'height': height + "px",  'min-height': 100 + "px"});
}
```